# How to sum values from different dataframes in r?

Tags: r, dataframe, sum

Hi I would like to sum  values (colum`sum`) by different levels (colum `users`) and reported in different dataframes. Sometimes the users are not reported in both dataframes.
My first dataframe is:

```
> head(reshape25)
         users      sum                  L1
1 00250902DC7D 30.15000 2014-01-14 06:30:00
2 00250902DC7D 29.68333 2014-01-14 10:30:00
3 00250902DC7D 26.15000 2014-01-14 18:00:00
4 00250902DC7D 28.73333 2014-01-15 02:30:00
5 00250902FB05 28.73333 2014-01-15 02:30:00
6 002509030C41 28.73333 2014-01-15 02:30:00   

> head(reshape52)
         users      sum                  L1
1 00250902FA92  0.25000 2014-01-20 01:00:00
2 00250902FB05  0.25000 2014-01-20 01:00:00
3 002509030C41  0.25000 2014-01-20 01:00:00
4 00250902FA92  0.80000 2014-01-20 07:00:00
5 00250902FB05  0.80000 2014-01-20 07:00:00
6 002509030C41 29.68333 2014-01-20 07:00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

If all of the data frames are of the same structure, you can just combine the data sets and then ddply the combined

```
library(gdata)
combined_dfs <- combine(reshape25, reshape52)
ddply(combined_dfs, .(users), summarise, sum = sum(sum))

         users       sum
1 00250902DC7D 114.71666
2 00250902FB05  29.78333
3 002509030C41  58.66666
4 00250902FA92   1.05000
```

Answer (score 0):

```
tapply(rbind(df1,df2)$sum,rbind(df1,df2)$users,sum)
```